# Parallel computing: add files

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I need my code inside the parfor loop to access/load two files. Unfortunately, that does not work.

The error message I get is

```
Error using **parallel.Pool/addAttachedFiles** (line 23)
Expected input number 1, pool, to be nonempty.
```

Here is the relevant part of the code I am using:

```
parpool(16);
    parfor k = 1:length(filenames)

    tmpfile = filenames{k};
    file_VPn = dir(strcat(tmpfile));
    load(strcat(file_VPn(1).name));

    % Attach files
    poolobj = gcp;

    addAttachedFiles(poolobj,{'/home/brainsig/Christine_fSON_MEG/Analysis_Code/elecs_grads_originfo/elec_field_orig.mat',...
    '/home/brainsig/Christine_fSON_MEG/Analysis_Code/elecs_grads_originfo/grad_field_orig.mat'})


    %% Fix excluded sensors (!!this is where I need the attached files)

    data_segm_clean.elec = '/home/brainsig/Christine_fSON_MEG/Analysis_Code/elecs_grads_originfo/elec_field_orig.mat';
    data_segm_clean.grad = '/home/brainsig/Christine_fSON_MEG/Analysis_Code/elecs_grads_originfo/grad_field_orig.mat';

    % [.............] rest of the code
end
```

Anything you can spot? Thanks!

Comment: loading files inside a parpool: not a good idea

Comment: Agree with @AnderBiguri. `addAttachedFiles` method is intended to add `.m` files and not data.

Comment: Right. Still, the error message comes up, since `gcp` does not return a valid pool object. `poolobj` is empty. Something went wrong when opening the parallel pool ...

Comment: Maybe you could try `poolobj = parpool(16)` and not use the gcp inside the parfor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the call to `addAttachedFiles` prior to the `parfor` loop.